# Javascript function works for first few iterations then fails

Tags: javascript, function

We use JS for opening and closing nav panels on our website.  Each navbar choice is an href link for when someone without JS enabled visits our website.  We are using JS to intercept the link and open the panels via CSS changes.

The function works well for the first few times it is called, then fails and the default link is followed.  There doesn't seem to be a set number of iterations before it fails, but nvbtn3 seems to be the one that it fails on the most.

Not sure how to sort out a cure. It is almost like it gets overloaded and quits.  Any suggestions?

Event delegation portion that looks for clicks on the navbar

```
$('mstrwrap').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // set eventlisteners for all A HREF links
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'A') {
    e.preventDefault();

    // check if is navbar link
    if ((e.target.id.includes('nvbtn'))) {
      // determine matching nav panel
      const nvpnl = e.target.id;
      const lk = 'nav' + nvpnl.match(/\d+/g);
      // open nav panel
      openNav(lk, nvpnl);
    }
    // end if navbar link

  // lots more possible targets

  }
}
```

JS function for opening navigation menus

```
function openNav(x, y) {
  // if already open, close it
  if ($(x).style.maxHeight === '100vh') {
    // close
    $(x).style.maxHeight = '0';
    $(x).style.zIndex = '';
    $(y).classList.remove('nvopen');
    $('nvbar').classList.remove('nvopen2');
  }

  // close any that are open, then open target
  else {
    // close all pnl, open specified pnl
    const targets = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="nav"]');
    for (let i = targets.length; i--;) {
      targets[i].style.maxHeight = '0';
      targets[i].style.zIndex = '';
    }
    const nvbtns = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="nvbtn"]');
    for (let i = nvbtns.length; i--;) {
      nvbtns[i].classList.remove('nvopen');
    }
    $(x).style.maxHeight = '100vh';
    $(x).style.zIndex = '5';
    $(y).classList.add('nvopen');
    $('nvbar').classList.add('nvopen2');
  }
}
```

We use a pseudo jQuery style variable

```
var $ = function (selector) {
  return document.getElementById(selector);
};
```

The navbar is simple href links

```
<a href="https://example.com/menu1.htm" id="nvbtn1">Menu 1</a>
<a href="https://example.com/menu2.htm" id="nvbtn2">Menu 2</a>
<a href="https://example.com/menu3.htm" id="nvbtn3">Menu 3</a>
```

Comment: Is there any chance the menu link contains nested elements, so `if (e.target.nodeName === 'A')` won't apply?

Comment: You could create a working reproducible example, before we start guessing...

Comment: Unrelated: `for (let i = nvbtns.length; i--;)` makes me think more than I want to when reading code.

Comment: @Bergi The links in the navbar are as you see (with of course the name and url changes)

Comment: @Legends the website is [link](https://pedalers.travel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bergi was right in the comments, that's why we ask to give the more details possible and ask for a reproducible example, because in simplifying the code for the question you got rid of the problem (trying to find the minimal example that cause your problem can help you solve it yourself, that's a good thought process)

Your links are not simply text, they have elements in them:

```
<a class="xp" href="..." id="nvbtn3">Book <span class="nvt">|</span><span class="nvd">Now ✎</span> Ask Us </a>
```

So your bug happens when you click on the small icon between the text, because the test `if (e.target.nodeName === 'A') { }` fails

EDIT (probably simpler):
There is another solution, using CSS `pointer-events: none;` on all elements inside your links, like the `<span>`. The event then should not trigger on the span but on the parent link instead.

ORIGINAL:
To solve this, you can use the following test, but be careful because changes in the structure of your `<a>` element can mess with it (a reliable solution would be to test the parent element recursively until you find you are in a link or not):

```
if (e.target.nodeName === 'A' || (e.target.nodeName === 'SPAN' && e.target.parentNode.nodeName === 'A')) {
  //your code
}
```

You can add other tests, like the class of the `<span>` if it fits your use case.

Comment: Or perhaps just: `if (e.target.closest('a'))`

Comment: @CherryDT I think actually the simpler would be to use `pointer-events: none;` on all elements inside the links, as I added in the edit. It should be possible with a single CSS rule

Comment: Thanks, the pointer-events suggestion worked like a charm.

Comment: @Tom you're welcome, good luck for the rest!

Answer (score 1):

**An alternative design proposal:**

Put the javascript disabled menu inside a `<noscript>...</script>` opening and closing tag pair. Possibly omit `id` attributes if they are only used for by JS, but not for styling.

```
<noscript>
  <a href="https://example.com/menu1.htm">Menu 1</a>
  <a href="https://example.com/menu2.htm">Menu 2</a>
  <a href="https://example.com/menu3.htm">Menu 3</a>
</noscript>
```

Put menu elements inside `nav` element(s) which have their style attributes set to `none` and a tab index for key navigation.

```
<nav style="display: none">
    <span class="navbtn" id="nvbtn1" tabindex="0">Menu 1</span>
    <span class="navbtn" id="nvbtn2" tabindex="0">Menu 2</span>
    <span class="navbtn" id="nvbtn3" tabindex="0">Menu 3</span>
</nav>
```

In JS startup code, after the body has been parsed, remove the `display:none` styling from `nav` elements:

```
document.querySelectAll('nav').forEach(el=>{
    el.style.display="revert";
}
```

---

- This design should work in browsers where the client has gone to some trouble to turn JS off. It won't work in browsers that don't support CSS and element `style` attributes.
- the content of `nav` element need not be links, and the example above shows made up `nav` child elements intended to be managed by click or keyboard event handlers. Actual child elements would depend on the application (and for navigation within page content could be links).
- The major benefit would be that code to "intercept links" would no longer need to be written or debugged.